# how does java check conditions with logical operators

Tags: java, conditional-statements

assume I have something simple like this:

```
if(condition_1 || condition_2) {
do something
}
```

if condition_1 is true, does java go on and also check condition_2?
I'm asking because I know if condition1 is true, condition2 will throw an error and I'm wondering if I need to make two seperate if's.

Comment: yep, I didn't know about short-circuiting and how to search it. sry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Java uses [*short-circuiting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operators:

- `if (condition1 || condition2)`  Condition 2 will only be evaluated if condition1 is `false`.
- `if (condition1 && condition2)`  Condition 2 will only be evaluated if condition1 is `true`.

**In general**: The second condition will only be evaluated if *needed*.

See [Java operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) for further information about this.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(condition_1 || condition_2) 
if condition_1 is true, does java go on and also check condition_2?
```

No!

Google [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) concept.

Answer (score 2):

You can also let check both conditions with using just one `|` token.

```
if (trueField | isButtonDown()) {
    //
}
```

Event if the first one is true, the method is called. With two `||`, it will not be called.